# Angular snackbar covering FAB when popping up

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, sass, angular-material

I have an action that gets fired in redux and the effect hits an API. When the API call comes back successful I throw up a toast via a service I have created to open the angular material toast (also done in the effect). This toast is covering a FAB that I have showing.

I am trying to figure out how to listen to the opening and closing of the snackbar in order to move the FAB up, when the toast shows, and down, when the toast closes. I would prefer to listen in the component where I have the FAB.

The Gmail app does this exact thing:
[Gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEVMa.jpg)

Comment: Hey Jordan. Good question. I would try to leave out some things that don't matter in your question or better yet an example in an editor like jsfiddle.net. Try to be more succinct and include an image or plnkr.co. Just leave it to the necessary details. Something like "I'm using Angular with Material. Toasts are covering my FAB button so I would like to move the button when a dialog is displayed".

Comment: Jordan. I don't have time to answer you question. I would probably make a ToastIsDisplayedService that is an int that is incremented when toast is opened and decremented when toast is closed. Then put the FAB in its own component and have that component listen to the ToastIsDisplayedService and change its display based on open toasts count.

Answer (score 0):

The returned instance after you open the snackbar is of type SnackbarRef<>,

it has several methods, of which two will interest you:

`afterDismissed()` and `afterOpened()` which return observables that will emit after open/dismiss.

You can expose these methods via the service you've wrapped around the toast, and inject that service in the FAB component and take appropriate actions.

Edit: link to the API: https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api